# В чем может быть причина, не отправляется данные второй раз js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть календарь `datarangepicker` в нем есть два поля

```
'<input class="form-control" type="text" name="daterangepicker_start" value="" />'
'<input class="form-control" type="text" name="daterangepicker_end" value="" />'
```

Когда первый раз отправляешь данные все нормально, но когда второй раз пытаюсь сделать отправку `input` поля пустые

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataRang').datarangepicker({
        opens: 'left',
        dateLimit: { days: 90 },
        locale: {
            applyLabel: 'Вперед',
            startLabel: 'Начальная дата',
            cancelLabel: 'Отмена',
            endLabel: 'Конечная дата',
            customRangeLabel: 'Выбрать дату',
            daysOfWeek: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт','Сб'],
            monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
            firstDay: 1,
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        }
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.applyBtn').click(function () {
        var start = $("input[name*='daterangepickerStart']").val();
        var end = $("input[name*='daterangepickerEnd']").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["account/company"]); ?>",
            data:{
                "id":"<?php echo Yii::$app->request->get('id');?>",
                "act_id":"<?php echo Yii::$app->request->get('act_id');?>",
                "start":start,
                "end":end
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.company').html(data);
            }
        });
     })  
});
```

`<div class="company"></div>`

У меня находится в самом начале для отображения календаря.
`<input type="text" class="form-control dataRang dateRang">` 
И получается когда первый раз оправляешь то все нормально, а когда второй раз то поля input пустые.

Comment: Странно, что в первый раз все уходит нормально: `name="daterangepicker_start"`, `name*='daterangepickerStart'`

Comment: Я сделал дубль `daterangepicker`  и подключил в файле где делаю вывод и переименовал поля по тому в первом файле  `daterangepicker_start` а во втором `daterangepickerStart` js идентичны за исключением название полей

Comment: Понятно, что ничего не понятно. Вы их заменяете, после первого запроса `$('.company').html(data);`?

Comment: Да в первом запросе отправляется  `name="daterangepicker_start"` а во втором я при нажатие на кнопку я получал пустые значения по тому я полностью все заменил, но после второго раза данные опять пустые

Comment: То есть вам нужно повторно инициализировать `$('.dataRang').datarangepicker` ?

Comment: Я не знаю как вам правильно объяснить, получается что я первый раз оправляю данные все нормально мене подгружает   `$('.company').html(data);` я второй раз отправляю данные тоже отправляются но когда третий раз отправлю то  `input[name*='daterangepickerStart']` приходят пустыми я не могу понять почему

Comment: Промисами пахнет. А ваши инпуты как заполняются, вами или datarangepicker?

Comment: нет мной, при повторной отправки приходит пустое значения, console.log(start) , не могу понять все отправляться без проблем кроме  daterangepickerStart  daterangepickerEnd

Comment: @Sender1050 попробуйте разместить пример на JsFiddle